# Adding an Image in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, imageview

How do you add an image in UIImageView? Whenever I click the drop down menu it just comes up with an empty white space. Where do you add the image?

Amar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image needs to be in your project for you to select it in interface builder.

Drag the image you want into your xcode project select `Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)` and try again

Comment: What do you select to drag the image in your project?

Comment: `File -> Add Files To "<name of your project>"` then find the file. If your a keyboard shortcut person `cmd + alt + A`. or simply drag from finder into your project navigator pain on the left hand side of xcode

Comment: I dragged it in from finder and it only displayed the image. Did not show up in IB or in resources.

Comment: Is the file in your project navigator? (The left hand pane showing all your files). If dragging didn't work maybe you dragged to the wrong place did you try the other two methods?

Comment: When I click add file what type of file should it be? Resource? Cocoa Touch Class? I'm just not sure what type of file to add. I know that my picture is a JPEG but I don't thing that makes a difference.

Comment: You need to click `Add Files To` and then you should be presented with a standard file dialog window to select any file you want. By the sounds of it you are looking at the dialog for `File -> New -> New File...`

Comment: When I click the file menu at the top there is no "new" button. I only have "new file" that leads to what I said before.

Comment: As I said in my first comment you want `File -> Add Files To "<name of your project>"` you do not want `new`

Answer (score 1):

On the right sidebar, theres an option to add the name of the image. i.e: `my_image.png`. As long as `my_image.png` is included in your project files, then it will show up in Interface Builder.